Running XCTests unhosted without adding a framework target
I'm interested in running a set of my app's unit tests "unhosted" in Xcode. When I attempt to do this I get an "undefined symbol" error from the linker when I try to use my app's types.
// Works fine
final class TheTests: XCTestCase {
    func testCoolThing() throws {
        let num = 5
        XCTAssertEqual(num, 5)
    }
}

// Linker error: Undefined symbol: GoodApp.CoolThing.init(name: Swift.String, count: Swift.Int) -> GoodApp.CoolThing

@testable import GoodApp

final class TheTests: XCTestCase {
    func testCoolThing() throws {
        let coolThing = CoolThing(name: "dog", count: 5)    // Type imported from my app
        XCTAssertEqual(coolThing.count, 5)
    }
}

I've tried a bunch of things, such as:

specifying GoodApp in Target Dependencies
adding GoodApp in Link Binary With Libraries
importing with and without @testable
scripts
updating search paths

and I'm still stuck in the same place. I feel like there's some fundamental piece of understanding I'm missing (i.e., compiled applications can't be imported as libraries and this approach is never going to work.) Any advice would be super appreciated.

The CoolThing object a structure? If so, then the standard init for structures doesn't work from another target, package, or library. Although @testable import was supposed to solve the problem. Try to explicitly define init in the structure. Also CoolThing code may clarify the problem.
struct CoolThing {
    let name: String
    let dog: Int

    init(name: String, dog: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.dog = dog
    }
}


Thanks for looking! I get the same error even if I explicitly define an init.
